# How to remove just added, one annotation?

Tags: ios, xcode, annotations

I have a lot of annotations on the mapView and user location dot. Then, if user tap for 2 sec. on the map, I add an extra annotation with options. I need to remove that last added annotation from map by pressing the button. How can I remove it without to remove any other annotation?

```
- (void)addPin:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)recognizer { 
    if(UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan == recognizer.state) {


        CGPoint tappedPoint = [recognizer locationInView:mapView];

        CLLocationCoordinate2D locCoord= [mapView convertPoint:tappedPoint toCoordinateFromView:mapView];


        MKPointAnnotation *annot = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
        annot.coordinate = locCoord;
        [self.mapView addAnnotation:annot];

    }

    if(UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged == recognizer.state) {
        // Do repeated work here (repeats continuously) while finger is down
    }

    if(UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded == recognizer.state) {
        // Do end work here when finger is lifted
    }
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17892362/how-to-delete-the-last-annotation-on-a-mapview

Answer (score 4):

To remove all the annotations from map view:

```
[vwMap removeAnnotations:vwMap.annotations];
```

PS: vwMap is the MKMap view object

Comment: Downvote for not answering the question.  He only wants to remove one annotation.  This would remove them all.

Answer (score 2):

Do the following,

If you have the annotation object

```
[self.mapView removeAnnotation:annot];
```

If you have the index of the object

```
[self.mapView removeAnnotation:self.mapView.annotations.lastObject];
```

Comment: If I use [self.mapView removeAnnotation:self.mapView.annotations.lastObject];
it removes user location

Comment: [self.mapView removeAnnotation:annot]; That work if I did that in same method, but how can I put it into button action?

Comment: create an ibaction for a button and then set the code inside it, are you facing problems with that?

Comment: No, remove lastObject doesn't remove just added pin

Answer (score 0):

Do this to remove your last added annotation in your delete Action:

```
[self.mapView removeAnnotation:[self.mapView.annotations lastObject]];
```

Hope helpful

Comment: by this it removes user location. Even if I add then another pin, it doesn't remove it.

Comment: Check for user location if count is 1 then u dont want to delete it eitherwise another annotation will be deleted if(![self.mapView.annotations count] == 1) { [self.mapView removeAnnotation:[self.mapView.annotations lastObject]];}

Comment: Now it doesn't remove anything

Comment: One annotation is for user location which will not be removed and other annotion just you added will be removed if u add the code i given in comment. Is this what u want?

Comment: I tried your code and it doesn't work for me. It doesn't remove just added annotation for some reason(

Comment: first annotation will not be removed but other than that will be removed as your requirement

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12191/discussion-between-safecase-and-pavel-kaljunen)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to remove the annotation object that is touched by doing the following, I know this wasn't the question but it may help someone out

set the mapView as delegate

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)thisMapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {

MKPointAnnotation *thisTouchedAnnotation = view.annotation;

uint8_t annotationCount = thisMapView.annotations.count;

for(int i =0; i<annotationCount; i++)
{
    if ([thisMapView.annotations objectAtIndex:i]==thisTouchedAnnotation){
        [thisMapView removeAnnotation:[mapView.annotations objectAtIndex:i]];
        break;
    }

   }
}
```

not flawless code but it may guide you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code!

```
NSArray *array=self.mapview.annotations;
for (MKPointAnnotation *anno in array)
{
    if(anno==[array lastObject])
    {
        [self.mapview removeAnnotation:anno];
    }
}
```